If $(z - \alpha_1) \cdots (z - \alpha_n) = p(z)s(z)$, then $p(z) =(z - \beta_1) \cdots (z - \beta_m)$.
Say we're working over the field of real or complex numbers, denoting this set by $\mathbf{F}$. Suppose we have the following equation of polynomials
$$
(z - \alpha_1) \cdots (z - \alpha_n) = p(z)s(z)
$$
for any $z \in \mathbf{F}$ and for some $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n \in \mathbf{F}$, and $p ,s$ are monic polynomials. My intuition tells me that $p(z)$ has the form $(z - \beta_1) \cdots (z - \beta_m)$ where $\{\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_m\} \subseteq \{\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n\}$, but I'm having a hard time justifying it algebraically, or in any other way.
Note, this question was inspired by my last question here.

Let $\{\beta_1,\beta_2,\ldots,\beta_m\}$ be the set of those $\alpha_j$'s which are roots of $p(z)$. Note that $p(z)$ has no root which is not a $\alpha_j$, since\begin{align}p(z)=0&\implies p(z)s(z)=0\\&\iff(z-\alpha_1)(z-\alpha_2)\ldots(z-\alpha_n)=0\\&\iff z\in\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n\}.\end{align}If we are working over $\Bbb C$, then we are done, since $p(z)$ and $(z-\beta_1)(z-\beta_2)\ldots(z-\beta_m)$ are two monic polynomials with the same roots, and therefore they are equal.
In the real case, it could happen that $p(z)=(z-\beta_1)(z-\beta_2)\ldots(z-\beta_m)q(z)$, where $q(z)$ is a monic polynomial with no real roots. But, in fact, $q(z)$ has to be equal to $1$. In fact, if$$\{\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\ldots,\gamma_l\}=\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n\}\setminus\{\beta_1,\beta_2,\ldots,\beta_m\},$$then\begin{align}p(z)(z-\gamma_1)\ldots(z-\gamma_l)&=(z-\beta_1)\ldots(z-\beta_m)q(z)(z-\gamma_1)(z-\gamma_2)\ldots(z-\gamma_l)\\&=(z-\alpha_1)(z-\alpha_2)\ldots(z-\alpha_n)q(z)\\&=p(z)s(z)q(z),\end{align}and therefore $(z-\gamma_1)(z-\gamma_2)\ldots(z-\gamma_l)=s(z)q(z)$. But it follows from the equality$$p(z)s(z)=(z-\alpha_1)(z-\alpha_2)\ldots(z-\alpha_n)$$that $\deg s(z)=n-\deg p(z)=n-m=l$. Therefore, since$$l=\deg(s(z)q(z))=\deg s(z)+\deg q(z),$$$\deg q(z)=0$ and then, since $q(z)$ is monic, $q(z)=1$.

Excellent! Thank you, I was able to follow this proof and can now be at peace.

I'm glad I could help.

This is similar to : on LHS a product of prime numbers $=$ on RHS a product of two numbers. Then one of the numbers is a subproduct, and the other is (the complement) subproduct.  Intuitive.
How to prove for polynomials? The basic result is this: if $p(\alpha) = 0$ then $p(z)$ is divisible by $z-\alpha$.   Also use: $u\cdot v = 0$, $u$, $v\in F$ then $u=0$ or $v=0$. Now let's get to work:
From the equality, put $z=\alpha_1$. On LHS we get $0$, on RHS $p(\alpha_1) \cdot q(\alpha_1)$.  The product being $0$, one of them is $0$. Conclude $(z-\alpha_1)$ divides $p(z)$ or dovides $q(z)$.  Now divide on both sides of the equality by $(z-\alpha_1)$ and continue... ( some induction here).
